# R: how to name dataframe rows with the folder names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to read text files from two sub-levels of folders 
and now I want to designate the rows and columns of the dataframe
with the *corresponding* folder names.

Sooo... for example,

```
folder1-----sub-folder A---text file<a>
       -----sub-folder B---text file<b>
folder2-----sub-folder A---text file<c>
       -----sub-folder B---text file<d>
```

I want my dataframe to look like this:

```
   | A      B
 --------------
 1 | a      b
 2 | c      d
```

One possible way to do is to make a vector of A&B and paste this
vector to the row names of the dataframe. However, since the actual 
number of folders and files is immense, I want to correspond the rows/columns
of the dataframe with their contents(which is file a, b, c, d).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `basename` and `dirname` might be helpful. So, if you have a list of filenames including paths, you can just create such a dataframe with these two commands.

Comment: This question needs to show what have you tried. What have you tried?

Comment: @coffeinjunky Oops Thanks I did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file names are random i can't answer yoru question. If however they are ordered by date or something similar like `Folder_1`, `Folder_2` think you can use the following:

```
 filepath <- "C/User/....(where the folders are)"
 pattern <- "Folder"
 Forwards_CSV_path  = list.files(filepath, 
                                  pattern = pattern, full.names=TRUE, 
                                  ignore.case=TRUE)
```

`pattern` is your search criteria within that particular folder 
the output will be a list of folder/file names.

since the output will only be the file/ folder name you might want to collect all folder and sub folder directory names and set up yoru directory addresses:

`paste0()` or `paste()` will help you bind together character vectors.

```
paste("c/user/,.....", "Folder_1")
```

once you have your sub folders you can loop over the addresses with the same code as above.

you can used `as.matrix()` and `cbind()` to convert them to your desired format and